# LazyLoading vs Prefetch in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After a lot of reference I came to know that `recyclerview` has two methods for efficient data loading one is `prefetch` another is `lazyLoad` . So , can anyone please suggest what's the best option to implement for loading data from server to `recyclerview`.

What I'm asking is which is faster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are Usefull for data loading from server. It depends upon how do you want to load data

1. If you want to show **Pagination** in `recyclerview` then use `lazyloading`
2. If you want to show **Cache Data** in your list than use `prefetch`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and great answer . But which is faster ?

Comment: in prefetch if data is large it take more time on first time loading ...but in second time it will load from catch so after once data loaded and stored in catch second time it will load fast...




.

in lazyloading data will load per page it means if you have a large amount of data..it will load small bunch of them and while you scroll down it will load again some bunch of data from entire ..so it will load on scrolling down

Comment: Thanks again sir for your meaningful explanation

Comment: can you tell me how to use lazy loading? what steps should i do please?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier   You can refer below link to get idea about it 


 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-with-example/